# Is 1331 a porous number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Porous numbers are numbers $k$ which are not multiples of 10 such that every m with sum of digits = $k$ and $k$ a divisor of both $m$ and rev($m$) has a zero in its digits. rev($m$) is the digit reversal of $m$ (e.g. rev(123) = 321).

Below 1000 there are only 11, 37, 74, 101 and 121 which fulfill these requirements (see [OEIS sequence A337832](https://oeis.org/A337832)).

Since $11$ and $11^2$ are porous, I wonder if $11^3$ and eventually all $11^n$ might be porous as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By creating random numbers , I finally found a number showing that $1331=11^3$ is NOT porous.

This is the $252$-digit number :

$$353825666971232183215917592547993744495841357998656914595823152857793685258835251136486926388153276487648939825745571369191664461982939148175161852945169978959436475151898734955879246341597631697429537824325715778878473864688738548526257969637457226557$$

No idea whether $11^4,11^5,\cdots$ are porous, but my guess is they are not.

Comment: Wow! I tried systematically by increasing the number in a while loop but my program was running for >24 hours without success. Did you choose the 252 yourself, or were your program given the freedom to select this as well? And how long was your program running until it found this number? - Thanks a lot!

Comment: That was not my first session. I slightly improved the speed, I just added digits until digit-sum $1331$ or more occured and repeated until this number was found. In total, it could have been $1-2$ hours, but I did not look.

Comment: Probably there are no further porous numbers beyond 121 and it would be nice to check this at least until 10000, but if it takes 1-2 hours for one number, then it would take too long to do it this way ...

Comment: Peter: Is your program written in Python (or Java)? Would you mind sharing it with me? I'd like to test if 1001 is porous ...

Comment: Try this code : por(n)={gef=0;while(gef==0,a=random([1,9]);q=a;while(q<n,s=random([1,9]);q=q+s;a=a*10+s);if(q==n,if(Mod(a,n)==0,b=fromdigits(Vecrev(digits(a)));if(Mod(b,n)==0,gef=1))));a}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116146/discussion-between-peter-and-rudi-jehn).